# Issue with select2 not searching data get from local json file with ajax call

Tags: javascript, json, jquery-select2

Can’t make select2 search data from local json file. Please help.
This is what I manage to compile form the net (sniplet below). (I am not a JS programmer nor Java ☹ ).

I am working with ManageEngine Servicedesk plus so not all things work and as you can see I for example need to use "$CS.element". The script is a part of a Forms and Rules functionality in issue template builder.

The example below almost work. It is displaying list for the select2. However, I can’t make it search.
I can select items with mouse click, but with typing I can only see that it is underlining the text in the list below search window and that is it.
[Select2-Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QFELf.png)

```
$CS.element('data-field').select2({
    ajax: {
        dataType: "json",
        url: "myfilelink.json",
        results: function (res) {
            var json_data = res;
            var data = [];
            more = "true";
            for(i = 0; i < json_data.technicians.length; ++i){
                var name = json_data.technicians[i].name;
                data.push({id: i+1, text: name});
            }
            return { results: data, more: more };
        }
    }
});
```